# How to convert UTF-8 txt files to all uppercase in bash?

Tags: locale, unicode, text, tr

I have some UTF-8 .txt files which I would like to convert to all uppercase. If it was just ASCII, I could use:

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

But since I'm working with diacritics and stuff, it doesn't seem to work. I guess it might work if I set the appropriate locale, but I need this script to be portable.

Answer (score 20):

All of:

```
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

(don't forget the quotes, otherwise that won't work if there's a file called `:`, `l`, ... or `r` in the current directory) or:

```
awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

or:

```
dd conv=ucase
```

are meant to convert characters to uppercase according to the rules defined in the current locale. However, even where locales use UTF-8 as the character set and clearly define the conversion from lowercase to uppercase, at least GNU `dd`, GNU `tr` and `mawk` (the default `awk` on Ubuntu for instance) don't follow them. Also, there's no *standard* way to specify locales other than `C` or `POSIX`, so if you want to convert UTF-8 files to uppercase portably regardless of the current locale, you're out of luck with the standard toolchest.

As often, for portability, your best bet may be perl:

```
$ echo lľsšcčtťzž | PERLIO=:utf8 perl -pe '$_=uc'
LĽSŠCČTŤZŽ
```

Now, you need to beware that not everybody agrees on what the uppercase version of a specific character is.

For instance, in Turkish locales, the uppercase `i` is not `I`, but `İ` (`<U0130>`). Here with the heirloom toolchest `tr` instead of GNU tr:

```
$ echo ií | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
IÍ
$ echo ií | LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8 tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
İÍ
```

On my system, the `perl` to-upper conversion is defined in `/usr/share/perl/5.14/unicore/To/Upper.pl`, and I find that it behaves differently on a few characters from the GNU libc `toupper()` in the `C.UTF8` locale for instance, `perl` being more accurate. For instance `perl` correctly converts [ɀ](http://www.charbase.com/0240-unicode-latin-small-letter-z-with-swash-tail) to [Ɀ](http://www.charbase.com/2c7f-unicode-latin-capital-letter-z-with-swash-tail), the GNU libc (2.17) doesn't.

Comment: For what its worth, I'm working with Czech letters (and the example you used is actually Slovak), where all uppercase letters are clearly defined, but locale set will probably be C and not Czech so that's a problem. Perl is already used in this toolchain, so adding another use might not be too bad. Thanks for the detailed explanation, btw!

Answer (score 7):

I think you can do this with `awk` and its `toupper` function.

#### For example

Doesn't work with GNU `tr`:

```
$ echo lľsšcčtťzž | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
LľSšCčTťZž
```

Works with GNU `awk`:

```
$ echo lľsšcčtťzž | awk '{ print toupper($0) }'
LĽSŠCČTŤZŽ
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks I changed the failing example.

Comment: That depends on the current locale and on the `tr` or `awk` implementation. For instance, most `tr` will correctly convert character when in a UTF8 locale, according to the current locale, GNU `tr` doesn't. `mawk` doesn't.

Comment: Actually, on FreeBSD (9.1), it's the other way round. It works with `tr`, but not with `awk`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I'm not as versed on the variances 8-). Someone just downvoted, wonder why?

Answer (score 2):

This works with OS X's `tr` but not with GNU `tr`:

```
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

This works with `gawk` but not with `mawk` or `nawk` (which is `/usr/bin/awk` in OS X):

```
awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

Another option is to use GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/./\u&/g'
```

In Bash 4.0 and later you can also use the `^^` parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r l;do printf %s\\n "${l^^}";done
```