# Convert file contents to lower case

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, tcsh, tr

I have `temp` file with some lower-case and upper-case contents.

### Input

Contents of my `temp` file:

```
hi
Jigar
GANDHI
jiga
```

I want to convert all **upper to lower**.

### Command

I tried the following command:

```
sed -e "s/[A-Z]/[a-z]/g" temp
```

but got wrong output.

### Output

I want it as:

```
hi
jigar
gandhi
jiga
```

What needs to be in the *substitute* part of argument for `sed`?

Comment: See also [How to convert UTF-8 txt files to all uppercase in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84942)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If your input only contains ASCII characters, you could use `tr` like:

```
tr A-Z a-z < input
```

or (less easy to remember and type IMO; but not limited to ASCII latin letters, though in some implementations including GNU `tr`, still limited to single-byte characters, so in UTF-8 locales, still limited to ASCII letters):

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input
```

if you have to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/g' < input
```

(here assuming the GNU implementation).

With POSIX `sed`, you'd need to specify all the transliterations and then you can choose which letters you want to convert:

```
sed 'y/AǼBCΓDEFGH.../aǽbcγdefgh.../' < input
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' < input
```

Comment: Please note that `\L` is a GNU extension.

Comment: `\L` works good for me so far. En light the point that you are trying to make **GNU extension**

Comment: @JigarGandhi. `sed` is a Unix command. Different systems have different variants with different behaviour and functionality. Thankfully, nowadays, there's a standard that most conform to so you can count on a minimum set of features common to all. `\L` is not among them and was introduced by GNU `sed` (matches the same operator in standard `ex`/`vi`) and is generally not available in other implementations.

Comment: `A-Z` matches the characters in between `A` to `Z` which [unless you're in the C locale doesn't make much sense](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763).

Comment: Note that some `tr` implementations like GNU `tr` don't work properly in multi-byte locales (most of them are nowadays, try `echo STÉPHANE | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` for instance). On GNU systems, you may prefer the `sed` variant or `awk`'s `tolower()`.

Comment: Slight correction: `sed 's/.*/\L&/g' < input`. The `\1` reference to the matched substring won't work unless you specify the substring with parenthesis as wurtle does in his. However, it's slightly cleaner to use `&` to represent the whole match, as shown

Comment: @EdwardBrown +1 but, also, the `g` isn't required, since `.*` picks up the whole line.

Comment: ```tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input``` works a charm, might want to add the following to the command ```tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input > output```

Comment: I wanted this as a command i can use, so poped in a shell script: `#!/bin/sh\ntr A-Z a-z` in ~/bin and `chmod +x`

Comment: @MarceloCantos, `.` won't match non-characters, so `.*` would not match the whole line if it contained sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale. Try for instance `printf 'ABC\200DEF\n' | sed 's/.*/\L&/'` with GNU `sed` in a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: On MacOS Catalina, `tr '[:lower]' '[:upper:]'` fails to convert a line containing only `7asdf` to uppercase. Must be a word-level conversion. Interestingly `tr a-z A-Z` converts that line to uppercase, so it must be operating at character level. Important difference!

Answer (score 35):

Using vim, it's super simple:

```
$ vim filename
gg0guGZZ
```

Opens the file, `gg` goes to the first line, `0`, first column. With `guG`, lowers the case of all the characters until the bottom of the file. `ZZ` saves and exits.

It should handle just about anything you throw at it; it'll ignore numbers, it'll handle non ASCII.

If you wanted to do the opposite, turn the lower cased letters into upper case, swap the `u` out for a `U`: `gg0gUGZZ` and you're set.

Comment: Lol "super simple"

Comment: this obviously doesn't scale well for many files

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg `vim file1 file2 fileetc` and then something like `:bufdo gg0guG:w<CR>` would *probably* work for any number of files. Have not tested that though!

Comment: @TankorSmash that still doesn't scale to a *large* number of files

Answer (score 19):

I like `dd` for this, myself.

```
<<\IN LC_ALL=C 2<>/dev/null \
dd conv=lcase
hi
Jigar 
GANDHI
jiga
IN
```

...gets...

```
hi
jigar
ghandi
jiga
```

The `LC_ALL=C` is to protect any multibytes in input - though any multibyte capitals will not be converted. The same is true for *(GNU)* `tr` - both apps are prone to input mangling in any non-C locale. `iconv` can be combined with either for a comprehensive solution.

The `2>/dev/null` redirect discards `dd`'s default status report - and its stderr. Without it `dd` would follow completion of a job like the above w/ printing information like how many bytes were processed and etc.

Comment: This solution is way faster than `tr` when handling large files, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can also use Perl 5:

```
perl -pe '$_=lc' temp
```

The option `-p` tells perl to run the specified expression once for each line of input, printing the result, i.e. the final value of `$_`. `-e` indicates that the program will be the next argument, as opposed to a file containing the script. `lc` converts to lowercase. Without an argument, it will operate on `$_`. And `$_=` saves that again so it will get printed.

A variation of that would be

```
perl -ne 'print lc' temp
```

Using `-n` is like `-p` except that `$_` won't get printed in the end. So instead of saving to that variable, I'm including an explicit print statement.

One benefit of Perl in contrast to sed is that you don't need any GNU extensions. There are projects which have to be compatible with non-GNU environments but which also already have Perl a s a dependency. Compared with `tr`, it might be that Perl `lc` can be more easily made locale-aware. See the `perllocale` man page for details.

Answer (score 9):

You need to capture the matched pattern and then use it in the replacement with a modifier:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\L\1/g' temp
```

The `\(...\)` "captures" the enclosing matched text, the first capture goes to `\1`, the next to `\2`, etc.  The numbering is according to opening brackets in case of nested captures.

The `\L` converts the captured pattern to lower case, there's also `\U` for upper case.

Comment: you dont need to do this - the whole pattern is always caught in `&`

Comment: True, but then I would have missed the opportunity to explain capturing matches :-)

Answer (score 2):

Further to MvG's answer, you could also use Perl 6:

`perl6 -pe .=lc temp`

Here $_ is implicit, and you don't need the single quotes to protect it from expansion by the shell ($_ being a special Bash parameter; see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

Comment: The www.gnu.org link you provide does not list Perl6's (now Raku's) `$_` "topic" variable as being used by Bash, at least not as a "Bash: Special Parameter".

Answer (score 1):

Using Emacs, you could first select all text in your buffer. Then invoke

```
M-x downcase-region
```